# Task :app:compileFlutterBuildRelease FAILED env: bash: No such file or directory

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I am trying to export `.aab` from my Flutter project to publish on the google play store and I got the error `Task :app:compileFlutterBuildRelease FAILED env: bash: No such file or directory` when the file was exporting. Can anyone help as I haven't experienced before while export `.apk` or `.aab` and my `gradle.properties` is as below:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
org.gradle.java.home = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.enableR8=true
```

Lastly I am working on mac OS